# Dúvida com PreparedStatement com INNER JOIN no Java

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida quanto ao uso do PreparedStatement com INNER JOIN, eis meu código:

```
public List<Emprestimo> pesquisar() throws SQLException {

    List<Emprestimo> listaEmprestimo = new ArrayList<Emprestimo>();

    String sql = "SELECT emp.cod_obra AS id_obra, ob.titulo, emp.dispo, emp.dataDevolu  "
            + "FROM emprestimo emp "
            + "INNER JOIN obra ob "
            + "ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obra"
            + "ORDER BY id_obra";

    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    listaEmprestimo = new ArrayList<Emprestimo>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Emprestimo emp = new Emprestimo();
        emp.getObra().setCodObra(rs.getInt("id"));
        emp.getObra().setTitulo(rs.getString("nome"));
        emp.setDisp(rs.getInt("status"));
        emp.setDataDevolucao(rs.getDate("dataDev"));
        listaEmprestimo.add(emp);
    }
    rs.close();
    ps.close();

    return listaEmprestimo;

}
```

Porém, quando eu compilo o código é retornado esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu faço a consulta, ela funciona. O que ocorre de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não está pondo espaço entre as coisas. Sua query está sendo montada assim: `... ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obraORDER BY id_obra ...`. Faltou espaço no fim de  `"ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obra"`. - fica a sugestão de imprimir o SQL na tela quando for fazer o _debug_ deste tipo de problema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pegando este seu trecho de código exatamente como está:

```
String sql = "SELECT emp.cod_obra AS id_obra, ob.titulo, emp.dispo, emp.dataDevolu  "
        + "FROM emprestimo emp "
        + "INNER JOIN obra ob "
        + "ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obra"
        + "ORDER BY id_obra";
```

Obtemos uma string assim (sem a quebra de linha, claro):

```
SELECT emp.cod_obra AS id_obra, ob.titulo, emp.dispo, emp.dataDevolu  FROM emprestimo emp
INNER JOIN obra ob ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obraORDER BY id_obra";
                                                ↑
      Aqui está o problema, falta um espaço ─ ─ ┘
```

Para corrigir o erro mencionado, troque isto:

```
        + "ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obra"
```

por isto

```
        + "ON ob.cod_obra = emp.cod_obra "
```

Este tipo de erro de digitação pode ser detectado com uma simples impressão do SQL gerado na tela.